# Renomear arquivo PDf antes de abrir para visualização

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, vue.js

Estou recebendo um arquivo PDF na response de uma requisição POST, e do lado do servidor eu configurei o nome do arquivo e tudo o mais. Mas agora eu estou visualizando ele no navegador ao invés de  baixá-lo e ele não obedece mais ao nome colocado no servidor e está atribuindo um outro nome, tipo esse: "2050102b-7041-4cfa-9ebf-0c05af158005" e não estou conseguindo fazer com que receba um nome específico
Alem do nome ser esquisito, a URL no navegador fica assim: "blob:http://localhost:8080/2050102b-7041-4cfa-9ebf-0c05af158005"

Servidor:

```
stream.on('finish', function() {
    if (fs.existsSync('C:/Projetos/Relatorios/pdfs/Tabela.pdf')) {
        let options = {
            root: '../pdfs/',
            dotfiles: 'deny'
        };
        let fileName = 'Tabela.pdf';
        res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err)
            }else{
                console.log('Arquivo enviado!')
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Cliente:

```
let link = document.createElement('a')    
link.target = '_blank'
let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.href = url .split('/')[0] + '/' + url .split('/')[1].replace(/.*/, 'meuarquivo.pdf');
```

Servidor: Express 4.15.0

Cliente: VueJS/Quasar-Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente configurar o header da resposta do servidor do content type pra PDF e o nome do Content-disposition para o nome do arquivo. Antes da linha do res.sendFile algo como:

```
res.set({
    'Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${fileName}`,
    'Content-type', 'application/pdf'
})
```